# How to fix a Jquery template ? problem with paragraph length

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, timeline

I would like to integrate this free to use Jquery template into a website : 
http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/timeline/demo23/

But when I try to include my own sentences in it, it brokes and is no longer responsive.

Would anyone have an idea about it, please ?

I tried to put on several p tags , and even to put a big sentence broken by br tags, or to put a list, nothing worked.

```
<div class="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="main-timeline">
                <div class="timeline">
                    <div class="timeline-icon"><span 
                       class="year">2019</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">
                        <h3 class="title">NEW YEAR</h3>
                        <p class="description">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="timeline">
                    <div class="timeline-icon"><span 
                       class="year">2018</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">
                        <h3 class="title">Confirmation</h3>
                        <p class="description">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                            adipiscing elit. Donec lacinia mi ultrices, 
                            luctus nunc ut, commodo enim. Vivamus sem 
                            erat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to obtain this timeline with my own sentences in it (as a list of small sentences, at best) and that the display of cards doesn't break when I change of page size. (so, that it stays responsive).

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

To change this styling for your own list, you'll want to edit the demo's CSS file, not the html file. To fix the boxes to include longer sentences, you can increase component size of the text box. Here's its definition in the Demo CSS:

```
.main-timeline .timeline-content{
    width: 35%;
    float: right;
    background: #f44556;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Increasing the width here might give you more space. Or, you can mess with the height in the timeline and main-timeline css classes.

From what I've done with the demo, the boxes already appear to be responsive to different screen sizes, but if you want to change their behavior you can use relative measurements of vw/vh. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp for all CSS units and how to use them.

Comment: It was the good place to make changes so that my text work. Thanks !